# How retrieve CHAR and VARCHAR field definitions depending on Firebird database encoding

Tags: encoding, firebird, database-metadata, firebird-4.0

In Firebird (4.0), I get the field length with following query:

```sql
SELECT T.RDB$RELATION_NAME, RF.RDB$FIELD_NAME, RF.RDB$NULL_FLAG, F.RDB$FIELD_TYPE, F.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH
    FROM RDB$RELATIONS T, RDB$RELATION_FIELDS RF,  RDB$FIELDS F 
    WHERE T.RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL AND (T.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL OR T.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0)  
        AND (RF.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL OR RF.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0)  
        AND (T.RDB$RELATION_NAME = RF.RDB$RELATION_NAME) 
        AND (RF.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE = F.RDB$FIELD_NAME) 
    ORDER BY T.RDB$RELATION_NAME, RF.RDB$FIELD_NAME
```

`F.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH` is the allocated size, i.e. if I have a `VARCHAR(256)` with `UTF8` encoding,  then the corresponding `F.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH` value is `1024`, but if this is default `NONE` encoded, the allocated value would be `256`.

Is there a way to find the actual value `X` of `VARCHAR(X)` directly within the query itself, depending on the database encoding?

In my case, I only have two possible encodings, `NONE` or `UTF8`, and I can check it with following query:

```
SELECT A.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_NAME containing 'UTF8' FROM RDB$DATABASE A;
```

will return `true` and field lengths should be divided by 4, otherwise simply return the value itself.

Should I build a query based on an `IF` statement on the above queries? If so, what would it be? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Use `RDB$FIELDS.RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH`, which contains the length in characters
2. Join `RDB$CHARACTER_SETS` and use `RDB$CHARACTER_SETS.RDB$BYTES_PER_CHARACTER` to calculate based on `RDB$FIELDS.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH`

An example including both:

```sql
SELECT T.RDB$RELATION_NAME, RF.RDB$FIELD_NAME, RF.RDB$NULL_FLAG, F.RDB$FIELD_TYPE, 
    F.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH,
    F.RDB$CHARACTER_LENGTH,
    F.RDB$FIELD_LENGTH / RCS.RDB$BYTES_PER_CHARACTER as calculated
FROM RDB$RELATIONS T
inner join RDB$RELATION_FIELDS RF
  on RF.RDB$RELATION_NAME = T.RDB$RELATION_NAME
inner join RDB$FIELDS F
  on F.RDB$FIELD_NAME = RF.RDB$FIELD_SOURCE
left join RDB$CHARACTER_SETS RCS
  on RCS.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID = F.RDB$CHARACTER_SET_ID 
WHERE T.RDB$VIEW_BLR IS NULL 
AND (T.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL OR T.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0)  
AND (RF.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG IS NULL OR RF.RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0)  
ORDER BY T.RDB$RELATION_NAME, RF.RDB$FIELD_NAME
```

You should **not** rely on the default character set of the database for this, because that only tells you the character set of newly created columns without an explicit character set. Each column has a character set, which was either specified explicitly or derived from the default character set **at the time the column was created**.

Comment: Awesome Mark, thanks so much (as usual :) )